# “Cannot get resource”error using “ kubectl describe” command

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

1.I  tried to get kubernetes cluster detail by entering command below .

```
kubectl describe service {NAME}
```

2.I got an error message below.

```
 error from server (Forbidden): servicies “max-Object-detectoer” is forbidden:User “{username}” cannot get resource “services” in API group “” in the namespace “default”
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the service account (user) you are using doesn't have access to that Service

You can create a ClusterRole like so:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: service-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["services"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

Then you can create a clusterRoleBinding, giving your service account the above mentioned role, like so:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding service-reader-pod \
  --clusterrole=service-reader  \
  --serviceaccount={name_of_service_account}
```

Let me know if this worked for you.